# highcharts trigger animation at every state changes

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using this library:'react-highcharts',  but I would like to upgrade to the official one: highcharts-react-official . This is my setup for the new one:

```
<ReactHighcharts 
        ref={ref => chartRef.current = ref} 
        options={graphConfig} 
        highcharts={highcharts} 
        immutable={true}
        />
```

wondering if there is an option like "isPureConfig" prop which will prevent it from re-rendering unless you pass in a different config object

Answer (score 1):

This is how `highcharts-react-official` works by default. If you keep chart options outside of a component, in a state or memorize them, the chart will not be re-rendered unless one of the wrapper component properties is changed.

You can play with the below example to test it by yourself.

```
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
      events: {
        render: () => {
          console.log("Chart render");
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-i4igu2?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: thanks, the issue was the ref, I just had to put chartRef